# What are some ways to debug/troubleshoot faulty USB ports?

Tags: usb, motherboard, external-hard-drive

I am using an ancient Gigabyte motherboard (GA-M720-US3). I noted within the last few years that one by one, the USB ports (2.0, perhaps earlier version?) fail to connect my large external hard drives for time periods longer than I need. Small USB pendrives, camera, and telephone have no issues.

The external HDDs do mount and show in Windows Explorer, however with issues: one HDD clicks for a while before mounting (disk manager shows its healthy and badblocks on a linux machine shows nothing to worry about); another HDD has no trouble mounting but robocopy cannot compare file structures for very long before timing out.

I assume there are no issues with the HDDs: about a year ago, I installed a PCI expansion card with two extra USB ports. This solution worked: the HDDs mounted with no issues at all. Backing up was without issue for this time, until now. And now I am getting the same trouble as I did earlier on the other ports.

What could be happening?

Can someone point me in the direction to successfully troubleshooting USB ports? Is there a diagnostic tool in Windows 10 or statistics in the BIOS that could tell me why the USB are failing?

Edit:  I am powering the HDDs from the USB port.

Anything would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do these external HDDs have their own power supplies or are you powering them from the USB port?

Comment: Thank you, I am powering them from the USB port.

Comment: Rather than the ports, it could be the *drives* requiring more power to boot / spin up as they age due to some mechanical wear perhaps. I have never considered it, I will look into it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thank you, that's a possible culprit, because the Samsung drive is approximately 10 years old (it's the drive that clicks that I mentioned above), however, the Seagate is approximately 2 years old and also shows trouble mounting and robocopy error timeout msgs.

Comment: It may be wise to add SMART reports to your post, smartctl or crystaldiskinfo being examples of tools to gather that data.

Comment: You might want to try a good quality powered USB hub, it might supply more power to the ports than your PC is capable of. You may well be overloading each port and wearing out the power supplies as they struggle to supply power. Capacitors in power supplies can degrade over time and may do faster when the power supply is under load.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Are these reports gathered while the drive is connected?

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for the suggestion. I assume you mean a USB hub with power supply. So, then would the hub be plugged into one of the mobo USB ports or the expansion card port? Or, do you presume that all the ports are dead and suggest that I obtain a new PCI expansion card into which I plug the hub?

Comment: I would suggest that the ports are fine as far as data is concerned, but that they can no longer supply enough power at a high enough level. Yes, a USB hub with its own power supply. As it only uses data to the ports on your machine it would not be straining your computer USB port power supplies and I expect it might well work better and be more forgiving about a HDD that is drawing slightly more current.

Comment: @Mokubai So we can assume that the motherboard detects the power needs of what's plugged in? (with the USB Hub plugged in and supplying power to an HDD, the mobo detects that it doesn't need to supply the power to the port--is that how it works?)

Comment: Yes, SMART queries the drives so they need to be attached. BTW regardless of what I said, I agree a powered USB hub may be all that's needed.

Comment: @Mokubai, Joep van Steen Thank you for the suggestion. I purchased a USB hub with power supple. The extra power seems to have fixed the issues: no more stalling, clicking, timing out. Thank you!!

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Although the USB hub appears to be a solution, it does not answer my original question. I think you came closest to answering the OP. So, if you modify your suggestion about "SMART reports to your post, smartctl or crystaldiskinfo" and perhaps add some extra information about how to execute their commands and read and interpret their reports, I will accept your answer below. Thanks in any case!